# How to use the RecyclerView selection library with ConcatAdapter?

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-adapter, multipleselection

I am implementing a RecyclerView of notes with a header. To implement the header I used a separate `HeaderAdapter` and merged it with my `NotesAdapter` using `ConcatAdapter`.

The header displays fine. But the multiple selection of notes is now broken, which was working fine before I used ConcatAdapter. I am using the official [recyclerview-selection](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/selection/package-summary) library for implementing multiple selections of notes.

Some strange things are happening like when I select the first note, the `onBindViewHolder` is called inside the `HeaderAdapter` and as a result the note's card is not checked.

Has anybody arrived with a similar situation?

**EDIT:**

I've found the primary problem. When we build the `SelectionTracker`, the Builder maintins a reference to the RecyclerView Adapter which is taken directly from the RecyclerView instance. As a result, whenever an item change happens, it all happens on the `ConcatAdapter` which is associated with the RecyclerView.

So I temporarily assign just the `NotesAdapter` before building the SelectionTracker and then assign the ConcatAdapter to show the header. See the code below:

```
...

binding.recyclerViewNotes.adapter = notesAdapter

// Setup the Selection API with RecyclerView
setupSelection()

binding.recyclerViewNotes.adapter = ConcatAdapter(headerAdapter, notesAdapter)

...
```

Now, the selection is working fine BUT with a small bug. On some occassions it selects two items instead of one.

For e.g., if I long press an item at position 0 it also selects the item at position 1.

Answer (score 0):

There's only like 3 results on the entirety of google that includes `"selectiontracker" "concatadapter"` and I just figured it out, so thought I'd share.

If you're using ConcatAdapter with selection-tracker, you have to use at least `1.2.0-alpha01`: `androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.2.0-alpha01`, versions prior to that don't support the new "absoluteAdapterPosition" that was introduced in RecyclerView 1.2, so return the relative adapters position instead of the ConcatAdapter position. This causes issues that make it unusable with prior versions.  It seems they've paused development for the recyclerview-selection, the lastest stable is 3+ years old, and that alpha is 2+ years.

In my viewHolder, I also use this for the item details:

```
fun getItemDetails() = object : ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long>() {
    override fun getPosition(): Int { return absoluteAdapterPosition }
    override fun getSelectionKey(): Long { return itemId }
}
```

Also of note, I'm using `setHasStableIds(true)`, so it might behave different without that.